# Getting wrong difference of dates column in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, datediff

I have one table which is having two columns as a DATETIME like following

```
CreatedDate                 DeliveryDate                Diff_Date
2013-05-12 18:30:00.000     2013-05-17 18:30:00.000     1900-01-06 00:00:00.000
```

I want Diff_Date for that i did sql query like

```
select (DeliveryDate -  CreatedDate) as  Diff_Date from MYTABLE
```

but i'm getting wrong answer :(

please correct me.

Comment: What answer do you want?  You are getting the "right" answer in a sense.  6 days is being represented as a datetime.

Comment: i dont know what makes you tell `above Diff_Date is wrong` ??

Comment: Specify datepart as in DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate) so that you understand it much clearly :)

Comment: I tried using  DATEDIFF with wrong syntax but it works fine 
my query is in sub query thats why it was not working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

For `MySQL` [**DATEDIFF()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) frinction.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DeliveryDate, CreatedDate) AS Diff_Date FROM MYTABLE
```

For `SQL SERVER` [**DATEDIFF()**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, CreatedDate, DeliveryDate) AS Diff_Date FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the number of days as an integer between two values then use:

```
select datediff(day, DeliveryDate, CreatedDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try DATEDIFF function.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use

Select    Datediff(DD, SmallDate,BigDate).

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DeliveryDate ,CreatedDate) as  Diff_Date from MYTABLE
```

For more information you can refer to documentation :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @CreatedDate datetime                              
    set @CreatedDate='2013-05-12 18:30:00.000'          
    declare @DeliveryDate datetime
    set @DeliveryDate='2013-05-17 18:30:00.000'

    declare @Diff_Date datetime
    set @Diff_Date='1900-01-06 00:00:00.000'

    --select Datediff(d,@CreatedDate,@DeliveryDate)
    select cast((@DeliveryDate-@CreatedDate) as datetime)

it returns same results as date_diff
-- 1900-01-06 00:00:00.000
```

## <kbd>[fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13433)</kbd>